# 'No Ads Found' With MoPub Native Ads and Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, mopub, facebook-audience-network

I'm attempting to understand why I'm receiving the **'No Ads Found'** error message.

## Expected

Native ads from the Facebook Audience Network (FAN) to show within the Android *RecyclerView* feed the same way the test ad units show in the screenshot below.

[image]

### Setup

#### Android

I have followed the [Android setup](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/getting-started/) for native ads. The app is not live on the Play Store as it is still in testing.

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
...
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="[app-package-here]">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="[app-package-here].MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.privacy.ConsentDialogActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*network_security_config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">cdn.example2.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

*build.gradle* (Module)

```
implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:5.4.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:facebookaudiencenetwork:5.1.0.0'
```

*build.gradle* (App)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha09"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
}
```

*MainActivity*

```
    val sdkConfiguration = SdkConfiguration.Builder([ad-unit-id-here])
            .build()
    MoPub.initializeSdk(this, sdkConfiguration, initSdkListener())
```

*Activity/Fragment*

```
private fun populateAdapterType() {
    moPubAdapter = MoPubRecyclerAdapter(activity!!, adapter,
                MoPubNativeAdPositioning.MoPubServerPositioning())
    val moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer = MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(
           ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_list_item)
                .titleId(R.id.native_title)
                .textId(R.id.native_text)
                .mainImageId(R.id.native_main_image)
                .iconImageId(R.id.native_icon_image)
                .callToActionId(R.id.native_cta)
                .privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_privacy_information_icon_image)
                .build()
    )
    moPubAdapter.registerAdRenderer(moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer)
    contentRecyclerView.adapter = moPubAdapter
    moPubAdapter.loadAds([ad-unit-id-here])
}
```

#### MoPub Console

*App*

[image]

*Ad Unit*

[image]

*Network*

[image]

*Segment*

[image]

## Actual

The test ad unit id *11a17b188668469fb0412708c3d16813* is showing successfully. However,  live Facebook ads are not shown when using the ad unit id created in the MoPub console.

**Error**: "MoPubNetworkError: No ads found for ad unit"

**Full Error**

> 2019-01-11 18:46:12.312 29624-29624/[app-package-here] D/MoPub: MoPubNative Loading ad from: [https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?id=[ad-id-here]&nv=5.4.1&dn=Google%2CPixel%202%2Cwalleye&bundle=[app-package-here]&z=-0800&o=p&w=1080&h=1920&sc=2.625&mcc=310&mnc=260&cn=Google%20Fi&ct=2&av=0.15&udid=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track&gdpr_applies=0&force_gdpr_applies=0&current_consent_status=unknown&MAGIC_NO=0](https://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?id=%5Bad-id-here%5D&nv=5.4.1&dn=Google%2CPixel%202%2Cwalleye&bundle=%5Bapp-package-here%5D&z=-0800&o=p&w=1080&h=1920&sc=2.625&mcc=310&mnc=260&cn=Google%20Fi&ct=2&av=0.15&udid=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track&gdpr_applies=0&force_gdpr_applies=0&current_consent_status=unknown&MAGIC_NO=0)
>
> 2019-01-11 18:46:12.689 29624-29624/[app-package-here] D/MoPub: Attempting to invoke custom event: com.mopub.nativeads.FacebookNative
>
> 2019-01-11 18:46:13.114 29624-29624/[app-package-here] D/MoPub: Successfully hit tracking endpoint: https://ads.mopub.com/m/attempt
>
> 2019-01-11 18:46:13.205 29624-29624/[app-package-here] W/MoPub: MoPubNative.onNativeAdLoaded com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNativeAdapter@708f83c
>
> 2019-01-11 18:46:13.206 29624-29624/[app-package-here] V/MoPub: Native Ad failed to load with error: A required renderer was not registered for the CustomEventNative..
>
> 2019-01-11 18:46:13.394 29624-29624/[app-package-here] D/MoPub: Native ad request failed.
>
> com.mopub.network.MoPubNetworkError: No ads found for ad unit.
>
> at com.mopub.network.MultiAdResponse.(MultiAdResponse.java:157)
>
> at com.mopub.network.MultiAdRequest.parseNetworkResponse(MultiAdRequest.java:96)
>
> at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
>
> at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)

## Potential Solutions

1. **Placement ID:** In MoPub Facebook was added as a network, but the wrong **placement id** was added. I've updated the placement id with the one generated from Facebook's Monetization Manager under the [Business Manager](https://business.facebook.com) tools.

With the correct placement ID the Facebook [*Ad Request Debugger*](https://business.facebook.com/pub/property/request_debugger) is showing requests being made by MoPub.

*Facebook Monetization Manager*

[image]

*MoPub Network Settings* > *App and ad unit setup*

[image]

*Facebook Ad Request Debugger*

[image]

2. **App Not Being Live:** Currently the app is in test mode so it is not live on the Play Store. However, according to Facebook's documentation *Your app won't be able to receive Audience Network ads until payout information has been added.* Payout information has been added, but Facebook's documentation does not specify whether the app must be live as well in order to receive ads.

I've also added a test device with my phone's *AAID* per [Facebook's testing documentation](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/2042606689358582) so not being live on the Play Store should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under MoPub's [Integrating 3rd Party Ad Networks](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/integrating-networks/) it explains that a unique [Ad Renderer](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/integrating-networks/#native-ad-set-up-your-ad-renderers) is required for Facebook in addition to using a [specific Facebook layout](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/native/#step-1-set-up-your-native-ad-layout).

> ```
> FacebookAdRenderer facebookAdRenderer = new FacebookAdRenderer(
> new FacebookAdRenderer.FacebookViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_list_item)
>     .titleId(R.id.native_title)
>     .textId(R.id.native_text)
>     // Binding to new layouts from Facebook 4.99.0+
>     .mediaViewId(R.id.native_main_image)
>     .adIconViewId(R.id.native_icon_image)
>     .adChoicesRelativeLayoutId(R.id.native_ad_choices_relative_layout)
>     .advertiserNameId(R.id.native_title) // Bind either the titleId or advertiserNameId depending on the FB SDK version
>     // End of binding to new layouts
>     .callToActionId(R.id.native_cta)
>     .build());
> ```
>
> To know which specific layout elements to use in your XML for the MediaView, AdIconView, and AdChoices RelativeLayout in the FacebookViewBinder, please reference this sample XML layout. Additionally, depending on the Facebook SDK version you are integrating, you will need to show only either the ad title or the advertiser name. For more information about Facebook’s implementation requriements, check out this article.
>
> Then, register your ad renderers, like below. Your classThatRegistersAdRenderers varies depending on which native ad integration you are using. Remember to register your MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer instance last.
>
> ```
> // MoPubRecyclerAdapter
> MoPubRecyclerAdapter classThatRegistersAdRenderers = new MoPubRecyclerAdapter(...);
>
> // MoPubStreamAdPlacer
> MoPubStreamAdPlacer classThatRegistersAdRenderers = new MoPubStreamAdPlacer(...);
>
> // MoPubAdAdapter
> MoPubAdAdapter classThatRegistersAdRenderers = new MoPubAdAdapter(...);
>
> // MoPubNative
> MoPubNative classThatRegistersAdRenderers = new MoPubNative(...); 
>
> classThatRegistersAdRenderers.registerAdRenderer(
>    googlePlayServicesAdRenderer);
>
> classThatRegistersAdRenderers.registerAdRenderer(
>   flurryNativeAdRenderer);
>
> classThatRegistersAdRenderers.registerAdRenderer(facebookAdRenderer);
>
> classThatRegistersAdRenderers.registerAdRenderer(staticAdRender);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Mopub Mediation with Facebook, you have to use `FacebookAdRenderer` in place of `MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer`